# BubbleSort on Double Linked List

Tags: java, data-structures

```
public Node get(int i) {  
    if (!isEmpty()) {  
        int j = 0;  
        Node element = head;  
        while (j++ < i) {  
            element = element.getNext();  
            if (element == null)  
                return null;  
        }  
        return element;  
    }  
    return null;  
}  



private void bubbleSort() {  
    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {  
        boolean changed = false;  
        for (int j = 0; j < size - i - 1; j++) {  
            if (get(j + 1) != null) {  
                if (get(j).getValue() > get(j + 1).getValue()) {  
                    //System.out.println("Swapping: " + get(j).getValue() + " : " + get(j + 1).getValue());  
                    swap(get(j), get(j + 1));  
                    changed = true;  
                }  
            }  
        }  
        if (!changed)  
            return;  
    }  
}  

public void swap(Node first, Node mid) {  
    if (first == head)  
        head = mid;  
    if (mid == tail) {  
        tail = first;  
    }  
    first.setNext(mid.getNext());  
    mid.setPrev(first.getPrev());  
    first.setPrev(mid);  
    mid.setNext(first);  
}
```

I dont know what is missing...

List, value:
6
2
4
5
7

After sort:
2
6
7

Auxiliar outputs:
Swapping: 6 <> 2
Swapping: 6 <> 4
Swapping: 6 <> 5

Please, some on help-me, I don't know sort a double linked list.....

```
public void swap(Node first, Node mid) {  
    if (first == head)  
        head = mid;  
    if (mid == tail) {  
        tail = first;  
    }  
    first.setNext(mid.getNext());  
    mid.setPrev(first.getPrev());  
    first.setPrev(mid);  
    mid.setNext(first);  
}
```

See the code following : swap function.

Comment: Is this a homework question?, if so tag accordingly

Comment: For starters you probably want either i < size or i <= size - 1... I think.

Comment: Post your swap function please. I have the feeling the issue is in there. Sorry if you had your swap function posted before, I didn't see the scrollbar ;)

Comment: Congratulations, you have found a way to make BubbleSort even slower than O(n^2) :-) Now it's O(n^3) because for each operation, you use get(i), which is another `*n`.

Comment: Why on earth would anybody (a) use bubble sort at all and (b) sort a linked list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is appears to be a homework question I will not give you the full answer. I am fairly positive that the problem lies in your swap function. Consider drawing the nodes on paper and going through your swap function and seeing what happens to which nodes pointing where. Consider the previous and next nodes of the nodes you are swapping and that you have to update their previous/next as well! Unless of course your setNext and setPrev functions already do that.

Feel free to comment if you need additional help.

Edit 1:

Also, as a side note, rather than using indices (i and j) to keep track of which node you're using, consider just using the node itself. And then when you call i++ or j++, call node = node.getNext() instead. This way you aren't adding an additional factor of n to your runtime, and you can eliminate your swap function altogether.

Edit 2:

What I mean by drawing it out on paper is write each of the values out on paper, in order, horizontally. Then draw a circle around each one and an arrow pointing to the next circle and the previous circle in each case. Draw the arrows in pencil! Then update the arrows accordingly as you step through your swap function. You don't even have to move/erase the circles, just erase the arrows and see where they point next.

Edit 3:

Okay so you've got two circles that you want to swap. These circles both have arrows going outwards, and their neighbors both have arrows going inwards. That's 4 arrows per circle (2 in, 2 out, unless you're dealing with the head/tail). Since you are moving 2 circles, that means you have to change a total of 8 arrows (unless dealing with head/tail) - 4 per circle. You're probably only changing one arrow per setPrev/setNext. Which implies that these should *usually* be called 8 times in your swap function. You're only calling them 4 times.

Edit 4:

You are updating the prev/next of the swapped nodes, but not of their neighbors. You're going to want to do something like first.getNext().setPrev(second), etc. to update the references/prev/next/arrows of the neighbors.

Edit 5:

Keep in mind null checks though (you can't call setPrev or setNext on a null, so make sure when you set the neighbor's prev/next that the neighbor actually exists (because prev doesn't exist for head and next doesn't exist for tail)).

Edit 6:

I *guess* if you *say* you aren't doing homework... ;)

```
void swap(Node first, Node second) {
    Node firstPrev = first.getPrev();
    Node firstNext = first.getNext();
    Node secondPrev = second.getPrev();
    Node secondNext = second.getNext();

    if (firstPrev) {
        firstPrev.setNext(second);
    }
    if (firstNext) {
        firstNext.setPrev(second);
    }
    if (secondPrev) {
        secondPrev.setNext(first);
    }
    if (secondNext) {
        secondNext.setPrev(first);
    }

    second.setPrev(firstPrev);
    second.setNext(firstNext);
    first.setPrev(secondPrev);
    first.setNext(secondNext);
}
```

Comment: I'm analizing but I can't see the problem, It does not a homework..
Its because I'm stidying data Structure, but I can't find examples..
Please be more specific in this problem anwer..
Thank you.

Comment: See my edit. What do your setPrev/setNext functions do? Just to be sure.

Comment: Oh, ok, I'll follow your example and see what is happening, if I find the error, I go psot here...
Thanks..

Comment: public Node getNext() {
  return next;
 }

 public void setNext(Node next) {
  this.next = next;
 }

 public Node getPrev() {
  return prev;
 }

 public void setPrev(Node prev) {
  this.prev = prev;
 }

Comment: I do this verification in the setNext/setPrev? ( into the method )

Comment: You can pretty much google "doubly linked list swap" and find something like what I just came up with too.

Comment: void swap(Node first, Node second) {
  Node temp = first.getNext();
  first.setNext(second.getNext());
  second.setNext(temp);
  if (first.getNext() != null) {
   first.getNext().setPrev(first);
  }
  if (second.getNext() != null)
   second.getNext().setPrev(second);
  temp = first.getPrev();
  first.setPrev(second.getPrev());
  second.setPrev(temp);
  if (first.getPrev() != null)
   first.getPrev().setNext(first);
  if (second.getPrev() == null)
   return;
  second.getPrev().setNext(second);
 }

<br>Now its working.. Thank you.