# How do i do a bubble sort with a double linked list?

Tags: java, linked-list, bubble-sort

I have a bunch of data in a double linked list, and i need to bubble sort the numerical data from this linked list

this is what i've been using in the past:

```
public void bubbleSort(int a[], int n)
{        
  for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++) 
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < n-1-i; j++)
    {
      if (a[j + 1] < a[j]) 
      {
        int temp = a[j];
        a[j] = a[j + 1];
        a[j + 1] = temp;
      }          
    }
  }
}
```

but i don't know how to get that to work with a linked-list, any help?

============================================

## Update at what i've tried

So i tried this method:

```
public StudentNode get(int i) {  
    if (!isEmpty()) {  
        int j = 0;  
        StudentNode element1 = header;  
        while (j++ < i) {  
            element1 = element1.getNext();  
            if (element1 == null)  
                return null;  
            }  
            return element1;  
        }  
        return null;  
    }  



public void bubbleSort()
{ 
    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) { 
        boolean changed = false;  
            for (int j = 0; j < size - i - 1; j++) {  
                if (get(j + 1) != null) {  
                    if (get(j).toBeSortedNumber() > get(j + 1).toBeSortedNumber()) {  
                        System.out.println("Swapping: " + get(j).toBeSortedNumber() + " : " + get(j + 1).toBeSortedNumber());  
                        swap(get(j), get(j + 1));  
                        changed = true;  
                    }  
                }  
            }  
            if (!changed)  
                return;  
        }  
} 

public void swap(StudentNode first, StudentNode second) {
    StudentNode firstPrev = first.goBack();
    StudentNode firstNext = first.getNext();
    StudentNode secondPrev = second.goBack();
    StudentNode secondNext = second.getNext();

        firstPrev.setNext(second);
        firstNext.setBack(second);
        secondPrev.setNext(first);
        secondNext.setBack(first);


    second.setBack(firstPrev);
    second.setNext(firstNext);
    first.setBack(secondPrev);
    first.setNext(secondNext);
}
```

butit doesn't even get to the `System.out.println` section and i can't work out whats wrong with it. Anymore help?

Comment: This looks like a bubble sort to me.

Comment: @foobar I tired looking at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8230019/bubblesort-on-double-linked-list but it didn't work with what i've already done

Comment: show us what you've already done and tell us what about it does not work.  you need to prove that you've done more than google for the answer before anyone is going to assist you.

Comment: @user112358132134 I've shown the way i've tried to implement it, any reason why it may not work?

Answer (score 1):

Since this is homework, I'll limit my answer to some hints:

1. The outer loop can stay as-is.
2. The inner loop is used to compare (and possibly swap) pairs of consecutive elements.

   - You cannot efficiently use random access with a linked list. However, having a loop that traverses the list once and looks the each element and its successor is very easy.
   - Swapping two consecutive nodes of a linked list can be made very simple, if instead of swapping the nodes themselves one swaps the *values* stored in the nodes.